# Any Emacs command like paste-mode in vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, copy-paste

When i'm trying to paste some code from browser to Emacs, it will indent code automatically, is there any way to stop Emacs from indenting temporarily like *:set paste* in vim?

Comment: Are you pasting into a terminal? This shouldn't happen if you're pasting into the GUI Emacs which gets the paste "directly"; when you're pasting into the terminal it's effectively like typing all those characters one-by-one.

Comment: Does this happen to in all modes/buffers?  Or just some?  Have you tried pasting into Emacs when you start emacs w/out your customizations (ala `emacs -q`)?

Comment: Didn’t know about 'paste'—thanks!

Comment: Prefixed `C-u C-y` should yank without indentation. Works for me with Emacs 25

Comment: @4e6 why did you put this in as a comment? This is a valid answer and easier than Jouni K. Seppänen's and I missed it on the first read.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The easiest way with emacs24 is:

```
M-x electric-indent-mode RET
```

*That disables auto indentation.*

Paste your thing.

*renable*

```
M-x electric-indent-mode RET
```

Or just `M-x UP-Arrow` ;-)

Comment: I'd love to be able to add a hook so that when I paste, this is automatically disabled and then reenabled. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I think you could by having your own key binding overriding C-c and calling a function that does this, calls the paste from CUA or other https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode

Answer (score 14):

Switch into the `*scratch*` buffer (or just to some nonexistent buffer; it will be in Fundamental mode, which shouldn't do any autoindentation unless you have somehow configured it to do so), type `C-SPC` to start the region, paste your text, type `C-w` to cut it within Emacs, switch back to your original buffer, type `C-y` to paste.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, though not *quite* the same thing.  For example, I note that this still gives a warning for mismatched parenthesis, when pasting in text (into a terminal-based Emacs instance) that has a smiley.  ( `:)` ) It'd be nice to have some sort of "mode" (using that term very loosely) that turns all such things off (because they can make the pasting take a long time, if it's a large chunk of text).  Still, this gets around some aspects, at least -- and clearly solves the original asker's main problem.

Comment: This doesnt work for a lot of inputs.The reason being when you paste windows/dos encoded text, the \r\n forces the appearance of a tab. Switch the file on windows to unix line endings if you can, and it stops

Comment: Pasting into the scratch buffer removes all indentation for me.  I would like to preserve the indentation that was originally there in the copied text.  The solution which disables electric-indent-mode works.

Comment: @ishmael The `*scratch*` buffer defaults to Lisp Interaction mode. Manually change it via `M-x fundamendal-mode`

Comment: This is the only solution that appears to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

A quick workaround for Python is to paste into a `""" ... """` block.

Answer (score 5):

Prefixed yank command <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd> would yank without indentation. Works with Emacs 25.

Comment: @Bae glad my comment helped, so I made an answer from it.

Comment: @ 4e6 here I am 2 years later googling for the same thing, and still missing this answer :) At least I've upvoted it now so I will find it 2 years from now...

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
c-toggle-syntactic-indentation
```

Comment: c-toggle-syNtactic-indentation

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo.  Fixed.